# Extract part of a text file for usage in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, substring

Ok. I need to store some records in a file namely `data.dat`.
Records in the file are sorted by date values. Each block of record starts with its date value along with a `$` sign to indicate that a new block of record starts here and ends with a "#" sign to indicate end of the record block.

A sample of a record block would be:

```
$22/08/2013
(data)
(data)
(data)
#
```

The file data.dat contains several blocks like this, how can I extract each block in the file storing each in an array using vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array i would use a `List(Of T)`. You could create a custom class:

```
Class Record
    Public Property DateValue As DateTime
    Public Property Data As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

Here's a possible loop to initialize the list from your file:

```
Dim allData As New List(Of Record)
Dim currentRecord As Record = Nothing
Dim currentData As List(Of String) = Nothing
For Each line In File.ReadLines("data.dat")
    If line.StartsWith("$") Then
        Dim dt As DateTime
        If Date.TryParse(line.Substring(1), dt) Then
            currentRecord = New Record()
            currentRecord.DateValue = dt
            currentData = New List(Of String)
            currentRecord.Data = currentData
        End If
    ElseIf currentRecord IsNot Nothing Then
        If line.EndsWith("#") Then
            allData.Add(currentRecord)
        Else
            currentData.Add(line)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me a Tuple quartet would be ready made for this.

```
Dim Record As New List(Of Tuple(Of DateTime, String, String, Integer))
```

Then each field can be accessed by it's item number:

```
Record(0).Item1
```